# How to call a function in javascript without HTML?

Tags: javascript

This is the function

```
function seeHTML(elem){
var htmlTxt=document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].innerHTML.toString();
elem.value=htmlTxt;
}
```

to call i use HTML

```
<input type="button" value="See HTML" onclick="seeHTML(txt)">
```

how to call it from another function as document.write

```
document.write(seeHTML(txt));
```

-- im a javascript begginer

however i tried document.write but it prints the function data itself, it doesnt use the function, how to ask it to use it then print the return (result)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't clearly get 1.) what do you want to print and 2.) where do you want to display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function foo(element) {
    seeHTML(element);
}

function seeHTML(element) {
}

foo(document.getElementsById('element'));
```

Answer (score 0):

in JavaScript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", call_your_function_here);
</script>
```

Here we created an event listener it means when the document is fully loaded the function() will be called, using the same way you can add any event listener to any DOM object, ex. you have a button with `id="test"`, `var btest = document.getElementById('test');` then

```
btest.addEventListener('click', function() { //execute code if btest object was clicked });
```

Bottom line you should call your function when the document is fully loaded hence replace the `call_your_function_here()` with your function name and if you wanted to reference the same button your function was embedded in use this syntax to reference the button DOM object:

```
var buttonObj = document.getElementById(buttonID);
```

then supply buttonObj to your function's argument.